# Camera track to constraint in the game engine

Tags: game-engine, camera, constraints

I have tracked camera to track a ball. When I move the ball manually, the camera tracks it. But when I apply motion using w,a,s,d keys to move it top, left,down and right, the camera stops tracking the ball. Why is this happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16624/how-do-i-get-constraints-to-work-in-game-engine

Comment: this link is exactly what I want to do but this doesnot help

Answer (score 0):

how did you do the constraint?

In BGE look on the "node logic" > "actuator" > "camera".

Send the .blend file if you need more help or video.